# Update all rows with different values in XML column [T-SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I would like to update a column(ColumnToUpdate) which is type of XML and exist in one table (SomeTable). And I would like to put to each row XML containing a list with new GUID

I know how to update XML inserting XML, but I don't know how create new GUID to each row. When I assign GUID to some variable in T-SQL -> then in not work cause it will be the same value.

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET ColumnToUpdate.modify('insert 
<SomeTag>,
 <ID Value=sql:variable(NEWID())/ID>,
 <SomeOtherTag>MySpecificValue1</SomeOtherTag>,
 <Tag3>True</Tag>,
</SomeTag>,
 <SomeTag>
 <ID Value=sql:variable(NEWID())/ID>,
 <SomeOtherTag>MySpecificValueTotallyDiffrent</SomeOtherTag>,
<Tag3>False</Tag>,
</SomeTag>
<SomeTag>
 <ID Value=sql:variable(NEWID())/ID>,
 <SomeOtherTag>SomeOtherName</SomeOtherTag>,
 <Tag3>False</Tag>,
</SomeTag>
<SomeTag>
 <ID Value=sql:variable(NEWID())/ID>,
 <SomeOtherTag>SomeOtherOtherName</SomeOtherTag>
 <Tag3>False</Tag>
</SomeTag>
(/SomeParentTag/childTag)[1]')
```

BEFORE

```
<someParentTag>
 </childTag>
</someParentTag>
```

AFTER

```
<someParentTag>
 <childTag>
  <SomeTag>
   <ID Value=GENERATED_NEW_GUID/>
   <SomeOtherTag>MySpecificValue1</SomeOtherTag>
   <Tag3>True</Tag>
  </SomeTag>
  <SomeTag>
   <ID Value=GENERATED_NEW_GUID1/>
   <SomeOtherTag>MySpecificValueTotallyDiffrent</SomeOtherTag>
   <Tag3>False</Tag>
  </SomeTag>
  <SomeTag>
   <ID Value=GENERATED_NEW_GUID3/>
   <SomeOtherTag>SomeOtherName</SomeOtherTag>
   <Tag3>Fasle</Tag3>
  </SomeTag>
  <SomeTag>
   <ID Value=GENERATED_NEW_GUID4/>
   <SomeOtherTag>SomeOtherOtherName</SomeOtherTag>
   <Tag3>Fasle</Tag3>
  </SomeTag>
</childTag>
</someParentTag>
```

This guids has to be unique, and also other rows has to have it uniqe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another table to generate a desired amount of nodes and insert them. Here is an example:

```
declare @t table (
  Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  XMLData xml
);

insert into @t (XMLData)
values ('<someParentTag>
 <childTag/>
</someParentTag>'),
('<someParentTag>
 <childTag/>
</someParentTag>');

declare @extradata table (
  SomeOtherColumn varchar(100),
  Column3 varchar(10)
);

-- Your data should come from somewhere, right?
insert into @extradata (SomeOtherColumn, Column3)
values
  ('MySpecificValue1', 'True'),
  ('MySpecificValueTotallyDiffrent', 'False'),
  ('SomeOtherName', 'False'),
  ('SomeOtherOtherName', 'False');

-- Before
select * from @t;

update t set XMLData.modify('insert sql:column("n.a") into (/someParentTag/childTag)[1]')
from @t t
  cross apply (
    select newid() as [ID/@Value], xd.SomeOtherColumn as [SomeOtherTag],
      xd.Column3 as [Tag3]
    from @extradata xd
      -- Artificial correlation to prevent result caching
      inner join @t tc on 1=1
    where tc.Id = t.Id
    for xml path('SomeTag'), type
  ) n(a);

-- After
select * from @t;
```

The correlation in the subquery is artificial and doesn't have any meaning in this example, however it appears to be necessary to prevent SQL Server from saving itself a bit of work and re-using the same XML fragment for all rows in the modified table. If, in your actual case, you already have some kind of correlation (for example, the generated XML depends on your main table in any way) then it should be sufficient.

Comment: I was not too specific enough that why I was edited my question, please check it. 
When I tried to use your example I receive error "An XML instance is only supported as the direct source of an insert using sql:column/sql:varialbe"
But thank you for your help

Comment: @dummyking, are you using SQL Server 2005? Inserts of XML fragments via the `modify()` method were first implemented in 2008. If that's so, I highly recommend to upgrade, as you are running an unsupported version. Also, it makes sense to check your database's compatibility level, it should be 100 or above. My example works on 2016, and it should work all the way back to 2008.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your changes.

Comment: Nice, thanks - I have almost this what I want. Cause this <SomeOtherTag> in my case has specific value like <SomeOtherTag>SomeName</SomeOtherTag> 
then in other Node the  <SomeOtherTag>SomeOtherName</SomeOtherTag>
and other tags are also specific. That's why I would like to insert huge xml but only GUID has to be generated as new and unique as you provide in your example. The rest of nodes of xml I would like to hardcoded which will be insert

Comment: Please @Roger Wolf check my last update in question.. I promise that this one is the last one :)

Comment: @dummyking, updated the answer. It doesn't really matter how you generate the rowset - you can use your other table that contains all these values (`@extradata` in my example).

Comment: Actually, I know what kind of data I would like to provide. And I am not keeping it in the table. But what if <SomeOtherOtherName> will have few children instead of bool value. Like 
<SomeOtherOtherName>
  <OtherOther1>Something</OtherOther1>
  <OtherOther2>Something1212</OtherOther2>
 <OtherOther3>Something213131</OtherOther3>
</SomeOtherOtherName>
The main thing is that I know the data I would like to insert. 
For each row I would like to put the 10 <SomeTag> with provided children. Each <SomeTag> in area of one row will be different. But for other rows will be the same. DESPITE GUID

Comment: You can include arbitrary XML fragments into the `for xml path()` subquery, just like you include scalar values.

Comment: Thank, but do you know how to create diffrent GUID for each row? Cause actual solution working in a manner that it pasting the same GUID to each row.. But in row the are diffrent

Comment: @dummyking, if you think the GUIDs will be identical then you haven't tried my code.

Comment: I've tried and they are diffrent when you want to update one row. But when you modify your code inserting one more row to table @extradata. ``` insert into @t (XMLData)
select '<someParentTag>
 <childTag/>
</someParentTag>';
```
then both rows will have the same 10 different guids. It means that 10 will be generated. But it will be populated to other rows.

Comment: I've put update set in while loop - to update each row with different guid 
WHILE @numberRowsToUpdate > 0 
 BEGIN 
  UPDATE TOP(1)
 END

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into it.

Comment: I couldn't find really fancy way to do it to have unique guid. Thats why I use WHILE LOOP, but also I could use CURSOR instead.

Comment: Indeed, very interesting. SQL Server calculates the inserting XML fragment once and then reuses it for all rows. I have added a correlation with the main table to break this. The execution plan will be worse, of course, but it still should be much better than any loop. I hope, that is.